# Is there a way to fight only the boss in a mission?

Tags: metal-gear-rising-revengeance

Is there a way to skip right to the boss fight while replaying missions? Or do I have to go through the entire thing whenever I want to fight one of them.

Comment: To enable the boss select, you need to beat the main story and Sam and Blade Wolf's stories.

Comment: @NamikazeSheena I still need to beat Sam and Bladewolf's stories, but if that comment is correct, feel free to post it as an answer.

Comment: why don't you try that and post your own experience as answer :D